How to make a BFS Algorithm in Micromouse Simulator?
I'm a beginner in Python. Basically, I need help in using bfs algorithm to explore all possible paths of a maze in Python to run in MMS(Micromouse Simulator. https://github.com/mackorone/mms. This is the link to the repository the app we are using). You can check the commands in the link I provided for the API import in the code. I have been trying to wrap my head around this for a day now, and I'm not making any progress. I need help in any way, whether the code or a guide, anything.
This is the code I modified and experimented with. I added the current position(cur_pos) and visited variables in hopes of a way for the mouse to check around areas, it visited to check for other paths and to use for deque, but I don't really understand it yet.
import API
import sys

def log(string):
    sys.stderr.write("{}\n".format(string))
    sys.stderr.flush()

def main():
    log("Running...")
    API.setColor(0,0,"G")
    API.setText(0,0,"S")

    y = 0
    x = 0
    cur_pos = (x, y)
    orient = 0
    visited = set()

    while True:
        #pathfinding algorithm
        if cur_pos not in visited:
            visited.add(cur_pos)
            if not API.wallLeft():
                API.turnLeft()
                orient = API.getCurrentOrientation(orient, 'L')
            while API.wallFront():
                API.turnRight()
                orient = API.getCurrentOrientation(orient, 'R')
            API.moveForward()
            x,y = API.updateCoordinates(x,y, orient)
            cur_pos = (x, y)
            API.setColor(x, y,"G")
            API.setText(x,y,f"({x},{y})")
            log(visited)
            log(f"Moving to {x},{y}")
        else:
            if not API.wallLeft():
                API.turnLeft()
                orient = API.getCurrentOrientation(orient, 'L')
            while API.wallFront():
                API.turnRight()
                orient = API.getCurrentOrientation(orient, 'R')
            API.moveForward()
            x,y = API.updateCoordinates(x,y, orient)
            cur_pos = (x, y)
            API.setColor(x, y,"G")
            API.setText(x,y,f"({x},{y})")
            log(visited)
            log(f"Moving to {x},{y}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Please explain in more detail what is not working and what you have tried. What is your specific problem? SO is not there to provide homework solutions.

You need to create a queue to keep track of the cells to be visited, and a set to keep track of the cells that have already been visited.

Initialize a queue with the starting position and a set with the same.

While the queue is not empty:
A. Dequeue a cell from the queue.
B. If it's the goal cell, you're done
C. If not, for each neighbor cell that is not a wall and has not been visited yet:
D. Add the neighbor to the visited set
F. Enqueue the neighbor

If you exit the loop, that means there's no path to the goal:


Here's the code implementation:
import API
import sys
from collections import deque
def log(string):
    sys.stderr.write("{}\n".format(string))
    sys.stderr.flush()
def get_neighbors(x, y):
    deltas = [(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 0)]
    neighbors = []
    for dx, dy in deltas:
        nx, ny = x + dx, y + dy
        if nx >= 0 and ny >= 0 and nx < API.mazeWidth() and ny < API.mazeHeight():
            if not API.wallPresent(x, y, dx, dy):
                neighbors.append((nx, ny))
    return neighbors
def bfs():
    log("Running...")
    start = (0, 0)
    goal = (API.mazeWidth() - 1, API.mazeHeight() - 1)
    queue = deque([start])
    visited = set([start])

    while queue:
        cell = queue.popleft()
        x, y = cell
        API.setColor(x, y, "G")
        API.setText(x, y, f"({x},{y})")
        log(f"Visiting {x},{y}")
        if cell == goal:
            log("Goal reached! ")
            return
        for neighbor in get_neighbors(x, y):
            if neighbor not in visited:
                visited.add(neighbor)
                queue.append(neighbor)
    log("No path to the goal.")
if __name__ == "__main__":
   bfs()


Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Mouse PathFinder\Main.py", line 42, in <module>     bfs()   File "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Mouse PathFinder\Main.py", line 35, in bfs     for neighbor in get_neighbors(x, y):                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Users\admin\Downloads\Mouse PathFinder\Main.py", line 15, in get_neighbors     if not API.wallPresent(x, y, dx, dy):            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: module 'API' has no attribute 'wallPresent'
it shows these errors when i run it through mms. do i need to make functions for them?

You should implement in your own API a module that does exactly what it's name suggests. Return true if there is a wall in the specified direction in which we want to check for a wall. My time is limited and I cannot code exactly everything .
